# CWAC-Cam2 prerecorded video instead of camera

Tags: android, cwac-camera

I'm building app using CWAC-Cam2 library. I need to test different application behaviour depending on objects exist on captured pictures. Is it possible to feed to the library video from a video file instead of actual camera output to simulate real environment conditions?

Thank you.

Sincerely,
Sergey